# Invariant sets of competing species with limited growth

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have problems identifying the invariant sets of the following dynamical system. Let $\mu,\lambda,\alpha>0$ and lets focus our attention in the first quadrant, $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$ .
$$\dot x = (1-y-\lambda x)x$$
$$\dot y = \alpha(1-x-\mu y)y$$

I know that the invariant set has to be the points where the trajectories stays where they begin. Thats why I know that the origin in this case is invariant. Now, other possible invariant sets are the points where we have an equilibrium, and in this case the points are $(0,0),(0,\frac{1}{\mu}),(\frac{1}{\lambda}0,)$ and if $(1-y-\lambda x), (1-y-\lambda x)$ intersect, we have $(\frac{1-\mu}{1-\lambda},\frac{1-\lambda}{1-\mu\lambda})$. Since I know that in all of those points, $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ are $0$, then what is the difference between invariant sets and fixed/equilibrium points? What would be all the invariant sets for this system?

Thanks so much :)

Comment: An invariant set is a set that consists of full trajectories of the system. Thus invariant sets could be something else besides equilibria. You can check that $\lbrace x = 0 \rbrace$ and $\lbrace y = 0 \rbrace$ are also invariant sets of this system.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, the thing is I don't fully understand how to cover all the possible cases :/ . Could you please elaborate? Thanks so much again for your time.

Comment: If I were you, I would ask the teacher to clarify the question. As you see, there are plenty of invariant sets here: pick any number of system's trajectories, take their union — here, it's another invariant set. Some invariant sets are more important, like compact invariant sets: equilibria, closed trajectories, unions of saddle equilibria joined by separatrices connecting them. Usually these are the most important in two-dimensional systems. But it's better to ask teacher.